# NoHostAvailable for select from solr_admin

Tags: solr, cassandra, datastax

we have two Data Center  when set CONSISTENCY QUORUM  select * from solr_admin.solr_resources . we get this error NoHostAvailable 
bout in anther dc every thank is ok .

Comment: For the two data center cluster quorum, you should have 4 replicates.

Comment: this for all keyspace ?